# UITextview - top space gets masked - Settings in XCode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitextview

In my app, I have a UITextview. This textview gets data from the DB and displays it. The data is properly fetched from the DB. But it is not getting displayed. The top portion of the textview is masked. Is there a setting in Xcode which I accidently set which is causing this issue. Please let me know. Because the code has no special settings for the UITextview. please find the image below for a better understanding

Thanks for your suggestions and effort.

[image]

Comment: Are you setting `contentInsets` anywhere ?

Comment: @Duncan Groenewald - I initially thought contentInsets  was the source of issue. I removed the lines. But still the issue persists. Thanks

Comment: What iOS version is this happening on?

Comment: @JustAnotherCoder - iOS7

Comment: Are you using NSAttributedString? First line's font color is black yet the 2nd is gray

Comment: Yes. I am using NSAttributedString.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the control above this one is doing the clipping, it may not a problem with this UITextView. What's the control above? Another UITextView?

In iOS 7 UITextViews love to overdraw. If this is the case, set `textView.clipsToBounds = YES`;

Comment: Good observation.I will check that now.

Comment: So is *anything* above this UITextView? On the UITextView exhibiting the clipping, do `textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]` so you can visually see its bounds. This might show something unexpected.